# How do I add the items to the ObjectListView properly?

Tags: c#, collections, objectlistview

another problem:
We're into a ModLoader at the moment, with a browse feature, which  works fine with the regular ListView. But we need to display an Image on a SubItem, so the ObjectListView came in very handy.

As soon as I started the program, I got the InvalidCastException, because I didn't used SetObjects(), so I set up a List of the type TroveSaurusMods and a class called the same. Adding items just works fine, but the items don't get displayed in the OLV. Can someone help me with this? And after that, help me with the image display?

Here is my code for adding the items:

```
private void getMods(ref ObjectListView location)
    {
        var lstItems = new List<TroveSaurusMod>();
        logger.log("Trying to add mods from TroveSaurus to the list...", Logger.logLevel.INFO);
        try
        {
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var jsonWeb = webClient.DownloadString("API LINK HERE");
                string json = js.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(jsonWeb))).ToString();
                jtr = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(json));
                JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
                {
                    var element = a[i];
                    JsonTextReader arRead = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(element.ToString()));
                    OLVListItem item = null;
                    lvBrowse.SmallImageList = imgSmall;
                    while (arRead.Read())
                    {
                        if (arRead.Value != null)
                        {
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "id")
                            {
                                item = new OLVListItem(arRead.ReadAsString());
                            }
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "name")
                            {
                                item.SubItems.Add(arRead.ReadAsString());
                            }
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "author")
                            {
                                item.SubItems.Add(arRead.ReadAsString());
                            }
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "type")
                            {
                                item.SubItems.Add(arRead.ReadAsString());
                            }
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "subtype")
                            {
                                item.SubItems.Add(arRead.ReadAsString());
                            }
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "fileid")
                            {
                                item.SubItems.Add(arRead.ReadAsString());
                            }
                            if (arRead.Value.ToString() == "filedate")
                            {
                                item.SubItems.Add(UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Double.Parse(arRead.ReadAsString())).ToShortDateString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //item.ImageIndex = i;

                    lstItems.Add(new TroveSaurusMod(item.Text, item.SubItems[1].Text, item.SubItems[2].Text, item.SubItems[3].Text, item.SubItems[4].Text, item.SubItems[5].Text, item.SubItems[6].Text));
                    logger.log("Successfully added " + item.Text + " to the list!", Logger.logLevel.FINE);
                }
                lvBrowse.SetObjects(lstItems.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve mod list from TroveSaurus! Please check your internet connection!", "Error parsing mods");
            logger.log(ex.StackTrace.ToString(), Logger.logLevel.ERROR);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And my class TroveSaurusMods:

```
public class TroveSaurusMod
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SubType { get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileDate { get; set; }

    public TroveSaurusMod(string id, string name, string author, string type, string subtype, string fileId, string fileDate)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Author = author;
        Type = type;
        SubType = subtype;
        FileId = fileId;
        FileDate = fileDate;
    }
}
```

I never worked with lists, only with the ListView. Please tell me, if I did something wrong and what I need to change :)
Thanks

EDIT: Found the answer... need to set the AspectName :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found out, that I had to set the AspectName for each column... sorry :O